# Cannot see WebService Role in WebLogic Console

Tags: web-services, security, weblogic, realm, wlst

I am trying to automate the following steps i do through WLS Console :

a. In the Weblogic console's Home page, click on Deployments link form left, find "gateway-management-service"

b. Expand, "gateway-management-service" and click on "GatewayManagementService" ( this is a webservice module )

c. Click on Security tab then the Roles tab.

d. Click "New" in "Web Service Module Scoped Roles" section.

e. In the new windows, set the name as "Special WS Role Enforcement" and click OK.

f. click on the link "Special WS Role Enforcement".

g. In the new page, Click on "Add Conditions" and select "User" in the new page and click Next.

h. In the new page, enter "CSR.gatewaywsuser" in the "User Argument Name", then click "ADD"

i. Click on Finish.

j. Save.

i have test.py as:

```
connect('weblogic', 'welcome123', 'localhost:7001');
realm=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();
xacmlatz = realm.lookupAuthorizer('XACMLAuthorizer');
xacmlrm = realm.lookupRoleMapper('XACMLRoleMapper');
resourceId = 'type=<webservices>, application=gateway-management-service, contextPath=gwy_management_service, webService=GatewayOidManagerService'
xacmlatz.createPolicy(resourceId, "Rol(Special WS Role Enforcement )");
xacmlrm.createRole(resourceId, "Special WS Role Enforcement ", "Usr(CSR.obigatewaywsuser )")
```

I run this script like :

```
$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh test.py
```

My problem : after executing the above script, when i go to Console -> Deployments -> gateway-management-service -> GatewayManagementService -> Security Tab -> Roles subtab, i don't see the Role. If try to run the script again it will fail with an weblogic.management.utils.AlreadyExistsException: [Security:090320]Failed to create role

What am i doing wrong?

I have tried bouncing both my managed and Admin server after running the test.py to see if that helps, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

You might actually be doing everything correctly. We have the same problem (roles not being displayed in console when set from wlst script). I think it is a Weblogic bug.

That said, you still have a method to verify the role has been set correctly.

In the Weblogic console go to:

```
Security Realms -> myrealm -> Migration -> Export
```

And export to a directory of your choice. You can then open XACMLAuthorizer.dat  and XACMLRoleMapper.dat and see if your role exists. You'll want to open it with an xml editor or browser as it's hard to read.